# How can I replicate boost::is_any_of() and boost::split() using standard library?

Tags: algorithm, boost, split, c++17

I am working on a small project, I want to convert code that uses c++14 to c++17.

But I couldn't figure out how to port one algorithm.

I don't have the boost library as I want to use standard C++17.

I haven't been able to convert the definitions of `boost::in_any_of()` and `boost::split()` . What can I do about it?

```cpp
        std::vector<std::string> materialVector;
        boost::split(materialVector, material, boost::is_any_of("/"));
                using namespace boost::algorithm;
```

I tried some methods I found on the internet, but I could not get positive results. I guess I don't know enough about this.

Comment: " I don't have the boost library as I'm using C++17" ???  Boost.Algorithm works fine with C++17.

Comment: @MarshallClow I was using the Boost library before upgrading the project from C++14 to C++17. However, during the upgrade, I changed all the boost:: definitions to std::, so I had nothing to do with the extern/boost folder. Finally, I deleted it completely. Currently, my project is completely c++17 and boost is not used anywhere. Since the project does not have a boost library, I cannot use the boost:: definitions. I want to use std:: instead, but I couldn't achieve this in the plugin I'm trying to add.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do that. Come up with unit tests, make them pass:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ac24bb2391cbf6b)**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>

auto f_old(std::string_view input) {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    boost::split(v, input, boost::is_any_of("/"));
    return v;
}

auto f_new(std::string_view input) {
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    std::string accum;
    for (auto f = begin(input), l = end(input); f != l;) {
        while (f!=l && *f=='/') {
            ++f;
            std::swap(accum, v.emplace_back());
        }
        while (f != l && *f != '/')
            accum += *f++;
    }
    v.push_back(std::move(accum));
    return v;
}

auto verify(std::string_view input) {
    auto o = f_old(input);
    auto n = f_new(input);
    std::cout << " ---- " << input << ": " << (o != n ? "mismatch!\n" : "match!\n");
}

int main() {
    verify("");
    verify("/");
    verify("a/");
    verify("/a");
    verify("aa/");
    verify("/aa");
    verify(" a/");
    verify("/ a");
    verify("a /");
    verify("/a ");
    verify("//");
    verify("a/bbb//c/  d/");
}
```

Prints:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
 ---- : match!
 ---- /: match!
 ---- a/: match!
 ---- /a: match!
 ---- aa/: match!
 ---- /aa: match!
 ----  a/: match!
 ---- / a: match!
 ---- a /: match!
 ---- /a : match!
 ---- //: match!
 ---- a/bbb//c/  d/: match!
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. But since my coding knowledge is not very good, I could not fully understand it. Some sources say that std::getline can be used instead of std::split. I don't know if it's true but I wanted to try it. But "vector<std::string> materialVector;"
I couldn't convert the materialVector variable here to type std::istringstream, it doesn't accept. Or maybe a conversion is needed to make it read by getline like this?